# ionic app on android with error message "detected problems with API compatibility"

Tags: ionic-framework, android-9.0-pie

I just walk through the ionic guidance to build an ionic app. After the app deployed on my android device, it always displays an error message "detected problems with API compatibility (visit g.co/dev/appcompat for more information)" as the enclosed screenshot.

I tried to package and deploy the app with Cordova and Capacitor. The same error message displayed. (yes, Capacitor actually based on Cordova).

I just walk through the g.co/dev/appcompat and do some search online. It is caused by Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces of Android 9. The app was created with ionic start template.

Anyone know the solution to dissolve the warning message? Thanks very much~

[image]